# Session Replication not working with tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, nginx, cluster-computing, load-balancing, session-replication

In my nginx I have set upstream and setup sticky session with:

```
upstream tomcat {
      ip_hash;
      server localhost:XXXX;
      server localhost:XXXY;
      server localhost:XXYY;
}
```

I have added `<distributable/>` tag in my web.xml (in all tomcats)

Have added this in my tomcat/conf/server.xml file:

```xml
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                 channelSendOptions="6">
          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                        address="228.0.0.4"
                        port="45564"
                        frequency="500"
                        dropTime="3000"/>
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                      address="auto"
                      port="5000"
                      selectorTimeout="100"
                      maxThreads="6"/>

            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
              <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
            </Sender>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>
          </Channel>

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                 filter=".*\.gif|.*\.js|.*\.jpeg|.*\.jpg|.*\.png|.*\.htm|.*\.html|.*\.css|.*\.txt"/>

          <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                    deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                    watchEnabled="false"/>

          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
        </Cluster>
```

Have added this in my tomcat/conf/context.xml:

```xml
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.BackupManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"
                   mapSendOptions="6"/>
```

But now I am able to login to my application. What happens is if all 3 or any 2 instances are started and I login, I see the JSESSIONID e..g xyz234.tomcat1

Now if I turn off tomcat1, it will take me back to login page since tomcat1 is shutdown. I login again and it creates session with say tomcat2, meanwhile, I turn tomcat1 up again, my application will take me back to login page. So, I face two problems:

1. I want to stay login even either of my tomcat (holding session) goes down.
2. And if that tomcat comes up again, I should still stay up.

Note: I am using JSF2 app, so not sure if it has anything to do with it.

Comment: A ***PrimeFaces*** `<h:commandButton>`?

Comment: @Kukeltje JSF Html tag :-)

Comment: @Kukeltje Any idea what might be wrong or what should I really look into?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't use replication, nginx or whatever. Only thing to do is to debug _"function does not even execute."_ and find the cause...

Comment: Great bounty, but I still think you can (and should) do more debugging yourself. See my comment above.

Comment: @Kukeltje I debugged it too much but unable to still find the cause.

Comment: I never said you should find the cause yourself... See [ask], the first paragraph... the thing about mentioning what you did... It is information (= data with 'value') for others. So they can more easily help out

Comment: To exclude one and other, do you have `<distributable />` set in webapp's `web.xml`? This is required when a WAR is to be deployed to a cluster.

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly so it is easy to understand (I hope) @BalusC

Comment: OK, so each Tomcat instance has its own session. This is actually not a programming problem, but a serveradmin problem and question is technically better at its place in http://serverfault.com. Unfortunately, bounty prevents migration.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? Should I create a new question in serverfault.com and give a duplicate reference in there?